# How to check name of a tag

Tags: tags

Per documentation I am getting a selected tag:

```
{% set tag = entry.myTagsField.first() %}
```

How to check if its name is equal to "Flower"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code returns an [TagModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/tagmodel) and saves it as "tag". You can now get all model properties like this:

```
{{ tag.property_name }}
```

In your case it would look like this:

```
{% if tag.name == 'Flower' %}
    Do stuff
{% endif %}
```